# How mongoose handle request even when the connection is not ready

Tags: mongoose

All:

I am pretty new to mongoose, when submit a query with a model like:

```
User.find()
```

How does it know the DB connection is ready, what if the connection is not ready, how does mongoose handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Usually there is a mongoose.once event that is fired.  You can then write the query code within the callback.

Comment: Mongoose queues "collection actions" (insert, remove, queries) in memory until the connection has been established (at which point it will perform all those actions against the database).

Comment: @robertklep That is also what I guess, but I just not sure how this implemented? Do u give some more detail?

Comment: @Kuan in the source code, queue handling [starts here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7cdc5aca179613aa1fb3bbacb2a926afa8174b16/lib/collection.js#L98). It seems to be relatively straightforward.